# kotlin Error Message "method 'void <init>()' not found"

Tags: kotlin, delegates

I was learning `by` keyword. I learned that when C delegates aProp and implements B and A overrides bMeth and implements B (C's instance).bMeth does the same thing as bMeth overridden by A for class A and top-level property aProp of A type and interface B and bMeth function of B and class C.so When i wrote the following code to experiment to confirm that fact and i expected output would be AClassf1 AClassf2 AClassf3 but output was

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: learn1.AClass: method 'void <init>()' not found
    at learn1.BClass.<init>(Experiment.kt:21)
    at learn1.ExperimentKt.main(Experiment.kt:6)
```

Why was i getting this message?
following code :

```
package learn1

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val bClass = BClass()
    bClass.f1()
    bClass.f2()
    bClass.f3()
}
interface AInter{
    fun f1() = println("AInterf1")
    fun f2()
    fun f3()
}
class AClass : AInter{
    override fun f1() = println("AClassf1")
    override fun f2() = println("AClassf2")
    override fun f3() = println("AClassf3")
}
class BClass(val aClass : AClass = AClass()) : AInter by aClass
```

Comment: Your first sentence is really hard to understand. Can you rewrite it to be a bit clearer? Also, can you include in your question what you expect your code to do?

Comment: I changed my code could you understand now?

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles and runs fine [on the playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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), and as expected it outputs:

```
AClassf1
AClassf2
AClassf3
```

How are you compiling and running this code?

This error is usually a binary incompatibility error when you compiled your code against some other class, but then you try to run it with a different version of that class on the classpath.

In your specific case, it's telling you it doesn't find class A's constructor (`<init>` is the constructor) when running B's constructor (probably when creating the default value for A).

Comment: i just looked in my another file and there was another version of AClass. thanks